# Excel Data Consolidation

Tags: excel

Somehow I managed to pull unique data from the list, but i am stuck with consolidation (merging data). I just created a sample file for easy understanding.

[image: sample image]

[Download Sample Excel File](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1WSO7u2khIdA1seKJAexdsGbadSNTY1_u)

Column A to E has data entered manually.

Formula used in H2 is `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($H$1:H1,$B$2:$B$11),0)),"")` This one is array formula which must be entered by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter

So now, column H has unique values from list B2:B11

What I need now,

In Column I, I2 must show area where highest duties performed. Like suresh did 10 duties in Guj & 15 duties in MH, then I2 must be MH

Column J should show the total number of duties done by that person, so I used formula in J2 =SUMIF(B2:B11,$H2,E2:E11)

Column K, should show data in the format shown in image, i.e. Unit-post-duties then enter charachter &CHAR(10)& or comma would do the job. THIS ONE IS TRICKY, I have no idea how to achieve this.

I am on Office 2019 Pro Plus Version 1909 (Build 12001.20000 Click-to-Run), I cant afford Office 365 (So no dynamic array and no unique function)

Thanks for all the support.

Comment: If you're familiar with Power Query (Get Data), you can get this done using that.

Comment: I prefer formulas over power query, Power query needs to be refreshed manually, although there are few VBAs available, but nothing is error free. Power query is not good in dealing with PROTECTED SHEETS. So I prefer formula for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question with the help of various forums and self experiments. Here is the solution.

First of all, make one helper column, Say F used as helper.

Formula for F2 is =C2&" "&D2&" "&E2&", "

Above formula joins text of C2, D2 & E2

Formula for H2 is

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($H$1:H1,$B$2:$B$11),0)),"")
```

Above one is Array formula requires Ctrl + Shift + Enter to enter the formula
Now, column H has unique values from list B2:B11

Formula for I2 is

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(MAX(IF($B$2:$B$11=$H2,$E$2:$E$11)),IF($B$2:$B$11=$H2,$E$2:$E$11),0))
```

This is an Array formula requires Ctrl + Shift + Enter to enter the formula
This formula shows the area code where highest duties performed, If duties are same for some particular person then it shows the first one found.

Formula for J2 is `=SUMIF(B2:B11,$H2,E2:E11)`

Formula for K2 is

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,IF(($B$2:$B$11=H2)*($F$2:$F$11<>"")=1,$F$2:$F$11,""))
```

which is an array formula requires Ctrl + Shift + Enter to enter the formula

Thank you